# Subquery in access with self-join, it does not recognize table alias

Tags: sql, ms-access, correlated-subquery

I built some subquery:

```
select 
    q2.addedquests, q2.daynum
from 
    qrNumberOfQuestsToDo as q2 
inner join 
    qrNumberOfQuestsToDo as q3 on q2.daynum > q3.daynum
where 
    q2.DayNum = (select max(q3.DayNum) from q3);
```

but MS Access does not recognize `q3` in the subquery. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Why not?  Because that is how SQL works.  You can *refer* to a column of `q3` in the subquery (in the `select`, `where`, `group by`, `having`, `order by`, or `on` clause for instance), but not to the entire table.

I am continuing, but I think the query is non-sensical.  In one place, the query says that `q2.daynum > q3.daynum`.  In another, that `q2.daynum = q3.daynum`.  Hence, the query will not return anything.  But, you can still express it as valid SQL.  Notice that `q3` is not really needed in the outer query. Try a correlated subquery instead:

```
select q2.addedquests, q2.daynum
from qrNumberOfQuestsToDo as q2 
where q2.DayNum = (select max(q3.DayNum)
                   from qrNumberOfQuestsToDo q3
                   where q2.daynum>q3.daynum
                  )  ;
```

Comment: You are right, it had no sense. I want to have the value of addedquests from the highest daynum that is simultaneously lower than daynum for which I want to check it.

Comment: @user1548483 . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question, including sample data and desired results.  It is a *different* question because you need help on how to phrase the logic, rather than  on understanding SQL syntax.